# How to show sum of all amount in textview and than to submit button?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and i want to know that when i press lets say Rs 10 or 20 etc than there total plus value should be shown in the textview amount and when submit button is pressed than the total value is saved in dabase and if clear button is pressed then the last entered value should be clear.How would i do this can anybody help in the form of code.? image is also attached.....

```
public class Sale extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn10, btn20, btn50, btn100, btn500, btn1000, btn5000,btnsubmit_sale,btnclearamount;
    TextView textViewamount;
    int sum=0;
    int total_sum;
    Intent intent;
    String email;

    public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "https://accountbook-a5340.firebaseio.com/";
    Firebase firebase;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public static final String Database_Path = "Sales_Details_DataBase";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sale);

        btn10 = findViewById(R.id.button10);
        btn20 = findViewById(R.id.button20);
        btn50 = findViewById(R.id.button50);
        btn100 = findViewById(R.id.button100);
        btn500 = findViewById(R.id.button500);
        btn1000 = findViewById(R.id.button1000);
        btn5000 = findViewById(R.id.button5000);
        btnclearamount = findViewById(R.id.btnclear_sale);
        textViewamount = findViewById(R.id.txtviwamount);
        btnsubmit_sale=findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitSale);

        btn10.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn20.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn50.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn100.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn500.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1000.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn5000.setOnClickListener(this);

        textViewamount.setText(getText(sum));

        intent=getIntent();
        email=intent.getStringExtra("email1");
        Log.d("email1",""+email);

        firebase.setAndroidContext(Sale.this);

        firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);
//        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        final SaleDetailSG saledetails = new SaleDetailSG();

        final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
//        int clicked_number = Integer.parseInt(btn10.getText().toString());

        btnsubmit_sale.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sum==0){
                    Toast.makeText(Sale.this, "Select any sale value to save into DataBase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Log.d("emailsale", "" + email+sum);

                    saledetails.setSale(sum);
                    saledetails.setEmail(email);

                    Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy--hh:mm:ss a");
                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05"));
                    String formattedDate = df.format(c);

                    // Adding the both detail and amount values using Expense details class object using ID.
                    databaseReference.child(formattedDate).setValue(saledetails);

                    databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

                    // Showing Toast message after successfully data submit.
                    Toast.makeText(Sale.this, "Data Inserted Successfully into Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    sum = 0;
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button10:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn10.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 10 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button20:
                sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(btn20.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 20 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button50:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn50.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 50 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button100:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn100.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 100 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button500:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn500.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 500 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button1000:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn1000.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 1000 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.button5000:
                sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn5000.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 5000 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: anybody please help i want to show the total value of  buttons in textview

Comment: can you tell me what is happening right now are you getting any exception or error

Comment: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0.

Comment: on textview where total value of "sum" variable should be shown

Comment: `textViewamount.setText(getText(sum));` what is this where is `getText()` method can you post the code of that method

Comment: in the switch case value of sum. I want to show value of sum in textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are not setting the sum value to your textView on each button click 
also to deduct the last value you have to add them in a `List<Integer>`
try this

declare the List like this

```
List<Integer> valueList=new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.button10:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn10.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 10 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum) //<-- change
                    //add value to list
                   valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn10.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button20:
                    sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(btn20.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 20 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum) 
                    //add value to list
                   valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn20.getText().toString());

                    break;
                case R.id.button50:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn50.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 50 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum)
                    //add value to list
                    valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn50.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button100:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn100.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 100 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum) 
                    //add value to list
                    valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn100.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button500:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn500.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 500 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum)
                    //add value to list
                    valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn500.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button1000:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn1000.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 1000 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum)
                    //add value to list
                    valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn1000.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.button5000:
                    sum= sum+Integer.parseInt(btn5000.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Rs 5000 Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum)
                    //add value to list
                    valueList.add(Integer.parseInt(btn5000.getText().toString());
                    break;
            }
```

then on clear button 
take the value from valueList in reverse order like this

```
if(!valueList.isEmpty()){
    int lastValue=valueList.get(valueList.size()-1);
    sum=sum-lastValue;
    valueList.remove(valueList.size()-1);
    textViewamount.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
}
```

to clear the textViewamount on submit
add below line in end of submit button code 
`textViewamount.setText("");`

Comment: now on button click "clear button i want to clear the last clicked value to be clear how to do that ?"

Comment: textViewamount.setText(String.valueOf(sum));

Comment: you have to deduct the last value from the `sum` variable and then set it to the textview

Comment: can you tell me in the help of code please ? how to deduct last value from sum and than set to text view?

Comment: see the edit to the answer and specially bottom part for the deducation

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1

Comment: getting error when button clear is clicked. my app chrashes

Comment: check the code of `onClick()` in my answer you have to add values to the list which you haven't done that's why this exception is occurring

Comment: i have applied your code of onclick and is working fine when saving values to sum but the problem is on clear button.when clear button is pressed than app chrashes and thhis errror occurs:"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
                      at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
                      at com.example.aliirtazakhan.firebaselogin.Sale.onClick(Sale.java:174)"

Comment: i have edited the code and added if loop to check the list is empty or not

Comment: when submit button is pressed than the value is saved in database ....its fine but "when submit button is pressed than the textview should be clear? "how to do that?

Comment: oh common just add `textViewamount.setText("");` in the end of submit button code

Comment: see how to accept answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i added "" valueList.remove(valueList.size()-1); ""in clear button code and it solves problem properly.because in your code the value was cleared but the last value left in array was adding to itself and giving display in textview in (-)minus form and also with addition of last value saved in array list ok.